# Numerically solving an ODE for a parameter

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

My equation is as follows:

```
sol = 
  ParametricNDSolve[{(f'[r]^2 - 1) f'[r] r == 6.2 (f'[1])^2/1000, f[1] == a}, 
    {f}, {r, 1, 3}, {a}]
```

where the function `f[r]` needs to satisfies a constraint `6.2 (f'[1])^2/1000 = 6 (f'[3])^2/1000`

Then I plot `f[r]`

```
Plot[Evaluate[{(f'[a])^2[1],6(f'[a])^2[3]/6.2} /. sol], {a, 0, 2}]
```

I am getting the message

> ParametricNDSolve::litarg: To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent 
>       variable in {r (NDSolve`f$1$1^\[Prime])[r] (-1+(NDSolve`f$1$1^[Prime])[r]^2)==0.0062 
>       NDSolve`f$1$1[1]^2,2 r (NDSolve`f$1$1^[Prime])[r]^2 (NDSolve`f$1$2^\[Prime])[r]+r (-1+
>       (NDSolve`f$1$1^[Prime])[r]^2) (NDSolve`f$1$2^\[Prime])[r]==0.0124 NDSolve`f$1$1[1] 
>         NDSolve`f$1$2[1]} should literally match the independent variables. >>

I do not know how to avoid the error message and solve the function `f[r]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message arises because there are three possible values for `f'[1]` that satisfy your DE:

```
Solve[(f'[r]^2 - 1) f'[r] r == 62/10 (f'[1])^2/1000 /. r -> 1, f'[1]]
% // N

(*
  {{Derivative[1][f][1] -> 0},
   {Derivative[1][f][1] -> (31 - Sqrt[100000961])/10000},
   {Derivative[1][f][1] -> (31 + Sqrt[100000961])/10000}}

  {{Derivative[1][f][1.] -> 0.},
   {Derivative[1][f][1.] -> -0.996905},
   {Derivative[1][f][1.] -> 1.0031}}
*)
```

If you pick one, the equation is solved:

```
sol = With[{df1 = (31 + Sqrt[100000961])/10000}, 
  ParametricNDSolve[{(f'[r]^2 - 1) f'[r] r == 62/10 (df1)^2/1000, 
    f[1] == a}, {f[r], f'[r]}, {r, 1, 3}, {a}]
  ];
```

Another problem is how `sol` is used in `Plot`.  You have to pass the parameter `a` to `ParametricFunction` to get an `InterpolatingFunction`; after that, then one can take the derivative and plug in `r`.  The easiest way that occurred to me was to ask `ParametricNDSolve` to return `f'[r]` in addition to `f[r]` and use that.  It's important not to use `Evaluate` here, because `r` cannot be replaced with a number until after `Plot` has replaced `a` with a number.

```
Plot[{(f'[r][a])^2 /. sol /. r -> 1, 
       6 (f'[r][a])^2/6.2 /. sol /. r -> 3},
 {a, 0, 2}]
```

The last problem is that the DE is inconsistent with the constraint `6.2 (f'[1])^2/1000 == 6 (f'[3])^2/1000`, but that I will leave with the OP.  For example, for the initial value for `f'[1]` used above, none of the solutions for `f'[3]` satisfy the constraint:

```
df1 = (31 + Sqrt[100000961])/10000;
df3 = Chop@
   N[f'[3] /. 
     Solve[(f'[r]^2 - 1) f'[r] r == 62/10 (df1)^2/1000 /. r -> 3, 
      f'[3]]];
6.2 (df1)^2/1000 - 6 (df3)^2/1000
(*
  {0.000251049, 0.00623853, 0.000226095}
*)
```